# How to change text box property to "shrink text on overflow"?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, textbox

I am trying to automatically shrink the text in a textbox to a proper size, on overflow.

There are similar functions for textboxes in PowerPoint and MS Publisher, but it is not in MS Word. I have searched the web and there are a lot of discussions on how to wrap text or to shrink the text to fit the width of a textbox.

I want the text box to wrap multiple lines and shrink the text size only when it runs out of space in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

Word has no built-in functionality for that. Word table cells have a 'fit text' option, but that forces the content to all fit on one line in the cell rather than condensing it just enough to fit the vertical height.

I wrote a macro for condensing text to eliminate minor line-wraps, which you can get from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40613-how-resize-paragraph-range-include-single-line.html. That macro could be adapted to do something similar for just a selected/nominated textbox. If you require more condensing than to eliminate just a short last line, further mods would be needed. For example, you might incorporate something along the lines of:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame
  Do While .Overflowing = True
    .TextRange.Font.Size = .TextRange.Font.Size - 0.5
  Loop
End With
```

Comment: thanks, macropod. I will try it later tonight. Does this macro automatically adjust the text sizes when there are too many characters in the text box without clicking any buttons or other triggers?

Comment: Not of itself - it's just a code loop that would form part of a larger sub. In any event, Word has no event-trapping that would automatically adjust the text size. The nearest you might get is something based on a WindowSelectionChange event, for which see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm and the demo code in https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ProtectWord2000PlusHeader.htm